# How do I add drag from right to left?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Good afternoon, I have a menu layout that should be pushed to the left by clicking on a button in another View, it works!

But, I need to add a Drag function to this Layout so that when Swiping from right to left, when it is open, the showMenu parameter is changed by the showMenu.toggle() method

The full code and a screenshot of how it looks is presented below, thanks in advance for your help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JONd5.png

```
import SwiftUI

struct MenuView: View {
    @Binding var showMenu: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Image("DefaultAvatar")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(maxWidth: 50,  maxHeight: 50)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Name Name Name")
                            .font(.system(size: 20).bold())
                            .padding(.trailing, 40)
                        
                        Text("Parent")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .font(.system(size: 12).bold())
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .padding(.bottom, 50)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 23).bold())
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .frame(maxWidth: 45, maxHeight: 45)
                        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors:
                                    [Color(red: 255/255, green: 119/255, blue: 46/255),
                                     Color(red: 255/255, green: 45/255, blue: 85/255)]),
                                                   startPoint: .topLeading,
                                                   endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                        .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 14, style: .continuous))
                    
                    Text("Persons")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                
                Spacer()
                Button {
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.turn.down.left")
                        Text("Sign out")
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                    .padding(.bottom, 50)
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 40)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .background(Color.white)
            .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous))
            .padding(.trailing, 40)
            .shadow(color: Color.gray.opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 10, y: -10)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        }
    }
}

struct MenuView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MenuView(showMenu: .constant(false))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use drag gesture like this:

```
.gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                .onEnded({ value in
                    if value.translation.width < 0 {
                        // left
                    }

                    if value.translation.width > 0 {
                        // right
                    }
                    if value.translation.height < 0 {
                        // up
                    }

                    if value.translation.height > 0 {
                        // down
                    }
                }))
```